# how to search result in codeigniter using age and cast

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**This is model i have to search result by using mysql and codeigniter result searching fine but it show all male but not showing age and cast properly**

```
 public function get_selected($age, $cast) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('bride_groom_register');
        $this->db->like('age', $age);
        $this->db->or_like('cast', $cast);
        $this->db->where("gender='male'");
        $data = $this->db->get();
        if ($data->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $data->result_array();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `like` and `or_like` use inside where condition. If you want provide gender also give in same line.

```
$this->db->where("age LIKE %$age% or cast LIKE %$cast%");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix('bride_groom_register') . " WHERE gender = male AND age = '".$age."' AND cast = '".$cast."' ");
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: @ yogesh  Call to a member function dbprefix() on null giving error

Comment: thanks for fast reply @yogesh  but it male is assume as column name gender is not take as column name error is Unknown column 'male' in 'where clause'

Comment: Sorry what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the `like` clause instead of the `where` clause?

```
$this->db->where('age', $age);
$this->db->where('cast', $cast);
```

or

```
$this->db->where([
    'age' => $age, 
    'cast' => $cast
]);
```